# Show posts between id 12 to 25 in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, limit

I want to do something more in posts. I want to show the posts between the ID 12 to 25.

Here is my code which is working fine and showing last 8 posts :

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
$args = array(
'posts_per_page' => 8, 
'post_type' => 'ourplant', 
'paged' => $paged 
);
query_posts($args);  

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

?>

I just want add something like `limit 12,25` which we use in php.

I have also tried something like this, but failed.

```
$args = array(
    'ID' => array(12,25),
    'posts_per_page' => 8, 
    'post_type' => 'ourplant', 
    'paged' => $paged 
);
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use offset param in your wp query.
it will list posts from defined specific point of value.
Use like this.

```
WP_Query(array(
            'posts_per_page'    => -1,
            'offset'            => 12,
        ));
```

Use order ASC or DESC if you want to get the posts in order.